# Can't search for jobs in Bengaluru

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I can't search job opening in [Bengaluru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore). It gives me zero results even though jobs are there. For example:

[An existing job listing in Bengaluru](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112876/senior-developer-java-j2ee-sap-ariba-technologies-india)

Is it happening for others or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you logged in when you perform the search? Have you set your current location in your profile?

Comment: I wasn't logged in, I logged to ask the question since it's required. Now it's showing up though.

Comment: Now it is showing up from another browser without logging in. @DeanWard did yo u fix it :)

Comment: He didn't, he's not telling you something.  Looks to me like jobs in India are only shown to users that can be verified to live in India.  Uh-oh, profiling, a very questionable practice in the USA.  Anything goes when money matters.  Have you tried Dubai?

Comment: @HansPassant no, nothing like that at all. Employers can choose which regions they advertise their jobs in. If you're anonymous we ascertain where the user is using IP address, if you're logged in then we use your current location from your profile or story (if you job prefs are set to 'include your home location') and we fallback to IP address. Suspect that saket may have been using an IP address that looked like it didn't come from India because he/she doesn't currently appear to have specified any [job matching preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current)

Comment: @HansPassant And to be completely clear: all the employers within that geo-radius have configured their advertising region to be India only, so those outside of the region won't see them.

Comment: So companies in India use profiling.  You helped them by giving them that option.  It all makes sense, doesn't it?  Money matters.  Whether that makes you look good even though you know damn well that this is a completely unacceptable practice in the USA is your cross to bear.  Boo.

Comment: @HansPassant Hmmm, that's a bit of a jump to make. A lot of companies don't provide visa sponsorship, so advertising regions help prevent them getting lots of applications that they cannot act upon. We allow candidates to specify the locations they're interested to work in by using their job match preferences. If they add locations they get shown jobs that only advertise within those regions.

Comment: @DeanWard Why does it matter whether I login and my job settings are set or not? Anyone having internet acccess should be allowed to search for a job by going to the URL http://stackoverflow.com/jobs and putting their preferred location in the location dropdown box.

Comment: @DeanWard Also Why is there an IP address filter ? Consider > A Indian student in US plans to return to India since he didn't get job in USA,he doesn't need sponsership and hence should be allowed to search job in his own country before he arrives (without login into the system,sometimes people only login when they want to apply).Also even if he logs in he need to change his current location to India else he won't be shown the jobs in India? how would a person know this, I don't think any other job portals works in this mysterious way.

Comment: @saket you don't need to change the current location to India, you can add additional work locations that you'd like to work in. The whole point of the functionality is to eliminate the scenario where somebody applies to a company that *will never reply to them*. This was happening a lot: candidates assumed that because the job appeared they could apply to it. From the employer side they're getting tonnes of applications which they cannot act upon. That's a bad experience for the candidate *and* for the employer.

Comment: @saket IP address is a fallback for registered users and all we have for anonymous users. /jobs gives a much better experience when logged in because we can make some attempt to apply ML algorithms to match jobs based upon your interests and locations.